# Tool to extract CSS used in visible part of page

Tags: css, optimization

Is there a tool out there that inspects a rendered website to extract/ highlight the CSS that is used to display the visible part of a page (viewport/ above the fold)?

My goal is to isolate these selectors and include them inline so the rest of the stylesheet could be integrated in the footer, in order to stop blocking the rendering of the page ([Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example)).

Comment: what you describe is common for javascripts, but not really for CSS...

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a link-only answer, this question is basically looking for exactly that.

[Critical](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical) gives you the CSS for everything that appears "above-the-fold", and may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Great. That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a tool that highlights your unused CSS, there are a couple of options:

- [ucss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ucss)
- [gulp-check-unused-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-check-unused-css)